# How can I check how many uses a tool has left?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a certain button that you push to see how many uses are left in a tool? If so, what button is it? I have seen a couple of YouTubers do this, but I've never known how to do it.

Answer (score 20):

Pressing F3 + H will toggle the display of item durability in the popups when you hover over an item in your inventory. This will also show the item ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a MAC or if the top answer's key combination does not work on your specific laptop, press the keys <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and the number of uses remaining will be displayed when you hover over that item.